# Executing a generic function every N times with a static variable

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a wrapper function that executes a given function every N times (something similar to Google logging's LOG_EVERY_N).

What I have done so far is:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template<size_t N, typename Callable, typename... Args>
void call_every_n(Callable&& c, Args... args)
{
    static size_t __counter = 0;
    if(__counter == N - 1)
    {
        std::invoke(std::forward<Callable>(c), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        __counter = 0;
    } else ++__counter;
}

#define CALL_EVERY_N(N, FUNC, ...) call_every_n<N, decltype(&FUNC), decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>(FUNC, __VA_ARGS__)
```

The problem is with the usage of the static variable for the internal counter but I cannot figure out how to achieve this differently. In fact, this code works as expected until I call the same function with the same N.

This is an example which demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <iostream>

void test(int a, int num)
{
    std::cout << num << " = " << a << "\n";
}

int main() {

  for(int i = 1; i < 20; ++i)
  {
      CALL_EVERY_N(3, test, i, 1);
      CALL_EVERY_N(3, test, i, 2);
  }

    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs:

```
1 = 2
2 = 3
1 = 5
2 = 6
1 = 8
2 = 9
1 = 11
2 = 12
1 = 14
2 = 15
1 = 17
2 = 18
```

i.e. the exact same static variable is used (and then modified) by the two different functions.

I also would like to enforce the fact that Callable must be a function returning void, how could I do it?

Comment: What exactly determines the uniqueness? For example if `main` would be called twice, should the counters be reset or not?

Comment: Unrelated: You could make it `void call_every_n(Callable&& c, Args&&... args)` (note the added `&&`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every lambda expression is of different type, hence you can use it as a tag:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N, typename Callable,typename Dummy, typename... Args>
void call_every_n(Dummy,Callable&& c,Args&&... args)
{
    static size_t counter = 0;
    if(counter == N - 1)
    {
        std::invoke(std::forward<Callable>(c), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        counter = 0;
    } else ++counter;
}

#define CALL_EVERY_N(N, FUNC, ...) call_every_n<N>([]{},FUNC, __VA_ARGS__)
// in each expansion, this is of different type    ^^
void test(int a, int num)
{
    std::cout << num << " = " << a << "\n";
}

int main() {

  for(int i = 1; i < 20; ++i)
  {
      CALL_EVERY_N(3, test, i, 1);
      CALL_EVERY_N(3, test, i, 2);
  }

    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/WjE74KT8b):

```
1 = 3
2 = 3
1 = 6
2 = 6
1 = 9
2 = 9
1 = 12
2 = 12
1 = 15
2 = 15
1 = 18
2 = 18
```

Only since C++20 the lambda expression can appear in unevaluated context (`decltype`), before a dummy parameter needs to be passed to deduce its type. You don't need to use `decltype` for the others, the template parameters can be deduced from the functions parameters. Perfect forwarding via `std::forward` requires universal references (ie `Args&&`).

Note that names starting with `__` are reserved for the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is to create a counter variable based on the line the CALL_EVERY macro is invoked and pass that in to call_every, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// template for calling a function, using lambda expresion

template<typename fn_t>
int call_every(int times, int n, fn_t fn)
{
    if (n % times == 0)
    {
        fn();
    }

    return n+1;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// helpers to create a variable for each CALL_EVERY based on line number
#define CAT1(a, b) a##b
#define CAT(a, b) CAT1(a, b)
#define VARIABLE_NAME(prefix) CAT(prefix,__LINE__)

// the full macro
#define CALL_EVERY(N, fn) \
     static int VARIABLE_NAME(call_every_counter_) {0}; \
     VARIABLE_NAME(call_every_counter_) = call_every(N, VARIABLE_NAME(call_every_counter_), (fn));

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void test(int a, int num)
{
    std::cout << num << " = " << a << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        CALL_EVERY(3, [&i] { test(i, 3); });
        CALL_EVERY(5, [&i] { test(i, 5); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think OP needs this to also work when a counter is not readily available. For example `void foo() { call_every(3,test,42,42); }`

Comment: Yeah that's a fair point :)

Comment: sorry, me again ;) Better use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to make it work also when the macro is used in two files on the same line.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number No problem if there is room for improvement there is room for improvement ;)

Comment: Despite the fact that, as @463035818_is_not_a_number said, I need it to work without assessing an external counter, this is somehow similar to what I ended up with. I mean, using an auto-generated unique name for the static variable.

Answer (score 4):

`CALL_EVERY_N` can create the static object:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct call_every_n
{
    template <typename Callable, typename... Args>    
    void operator()(Callable&& c, Args&&... args)
    {
        if (++counter >= N) {
            std::invoke(std::forward<Callable>(c), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    std::size_t counter = 0;  
};

#define CALL_EVERY_N(N, FUNC, ...) do { static call_every_n<N> call_every_n_var; call_every_n_var(FUNC, __VA_ARGS__); } while(0)
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15f1775f4b4d4068).

Comment: In this case, what is supposed to happen if I call, e.g.  CALL_EVERY_N(3, test, i, 1); twice ? I think the objects created will be exactly the same and then I would have the same problem as in my example.. am I right?

Comment: @JacopoLottero: The object is in a local scope, so additional MACRO usage would create another scope with another static variable. Demo call the MACRO twice. only problem currently is if you use the same name (`call_every_n_var`) outside and use it as MACRO parameter.